# Scala High Order Function

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, implicit

i want to make function as parameter of class construction.
i have some functions that i want to calculate in class (some kind of lazy calculation)

```
class Foo(calc: PGSimpleDataSource => Connection => PreparedStatement => ResultSet => Option[A] ??? ) {

  here some logic like:

  def runCalc = calc ( resultSet ( preparedStatement ( connection )

  resultSet.close()
  preparedStatement.close()
  connection.close()

  send result somewhere ...

}
```

prepare some functions

```
implicit val dataSource: PGSimpleDataSource = Service.ds

implicit def getConnection(implicit ds: PGSimpleDataSource): Connection = ds.getConnection

implicit def getPreparedStatement(userId: UUID)(implicit con: Connection): PreparedStatement ={
    val st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bar WHERE id = CAST(? as UUID)")
    st.setString(1, id.toString)
    st
  }

implicit def getResultSet(implicit ps: PreparedStatement): ResultSet = ps.executeQuery()

implicit def mapping(implicit rs: ResultSet): Option[Bar] = {
    Iterator.continually(rs.next)
      .takeWhile(identity)
      .map(_ => Bar(UUID.fromString(rs.getString(1)))).toList.headOption
  }
```

and then some function like:

```
def getInstance(id: UUID) = new Foo(???)

val foo = getInstance(id)

foo.runCalc()
```

Is it possible? Please Help

**upd:**

i tried to do my class like this :

```
class Foo[A](
                con: => Connection,
                ps: => PreparedStatement,
                rs: => ResultSet,
                mapping: => Option[A],
                calc: Connection => PreparedStatement => ResultSet => Option[A]
              ) {
  def run(): Unit = {
    val result: Option[A] = calc(con)(ps)(rs)(mapping)

    rs.close()
    ps.close()
    con.close()
  }
}
```

but i don't understand how to write "f" function as written below

it need do mapping( getResultSet ( getPreparedStatement (id, getConnection))

in other words mapping need ResultSet that need PreparedStatement that need Id and Connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. It will look like this

```
case class Foo(calc: String => String => String => Option[String]) {
  def run = {
    val p1 = "p1"
    val p2 = "p2"
    val p3 = "p3"

    calc(p1)(p2)(p3)
  }
}
```

Usage example

```
object App extends App {
  val f = (x: String) => (y: String) => (z: String) => {
    Option(x + y + z)
  }
  val foo = Foo(f)
  println(foo.run)
}
```

Or you can use currying

```
object App extends App {
  val f = (x: String, y: String, z: String) => {
    Option(x + y + z)
  }

  val foo = Foo(f.curried)

  println(foo.run)
}
```

**EDIT**

For you extended question I can propose this class:

```
case class Foo[A](
                   getConnection: () => Connection,
                   getStatement: Connection => PreparedStatement,
                   getResultSet: PreparedStatement => ResultSet,
                   mapping: ResultSet => Option[A]) {
  def run(): Option[A] = {
    val connection = getConnection()
    try{
      val statement = getStatement(connection)
      try{
        val resultSet = getResultSet(statement)
        try{
          mapping(resultSet)
        }finally {
          resultSet.close()
        }
      }finally{
        statement.close()
      } 
    } finally {
      connection.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
  val foo = Foo(
    () => new Connection(),
    connection => new PreparedStatement(),
    statement => new ResultSet(),
    resultSet => Option("")
  )
```

All those function have parameter from previous step so when for example you create `ResultSet` you can use `statement` (but you can't use `connection`).

Comment: This helps but not enough :) Please look at my update!

Comment: I don't get what is your problem there. You code in `calc(con)(ps)(rs)(mapping)` passing 4 parameters while `calc` expect only 3. Can you add explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Usual case a have 4 steps:
1 - try to get Connection;
2 - try to prepare PreparedStatement with connection.prepareStatement;
3 - try to execute query with preparedStatement.executeQuery();
4 - try to mapping result to case class;

In each step something bad can happen and my code looks like try in try in try ... because i need to close connection, statement and result set if a got them

I try to write all this routine once and after that my dba.getFoo(id: UUID) will be looks like def getFoo(id: UUID) = new DBRunner[Foo](getConnection, getPreparedStatement(id), getResult, mapping)

Comment: I got it. Will try to fix my answer.

Comment: thank you very much!
that's what I need.
now I can write: 

val foo = Foo(
    () => getConnection(ds),
    connection => getPreparedStatement(connection, id),
    statement => statement.executeQuery,
    resultSet => mapping(resultSet)
  )

  foo.run()

Comment: According Eta-expansion of zero-argument warning:
val foo = Foo(getConnection(ds) _, ....